# What is the number of followers seen on Tag subscription page?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, tag-filters, followers

I would like to know what the 3rd number in the screen shot is? It from this [design-pattern filter page](https://stackexchange.com/filters/2120/design-patterns) I recently subscribed to.

Hovering over the tag [design-pattern](/questions/tagged/design-pattern) on SO shows **3.5K** followers. So this is not even nearer to the number. I had somewhere read before that the number(3.5K) is the sum of users that has it as a favorite or has subscribed it.

So, in this case we see 183 email-subcribers, 3.5K follower(from the tag hover), then what is the below **7 users following**?

[image: Tag follower]

Please let me know.

Comment: I would imagine that, if it's in your list of "favorite tags," you are following it.  I've always kinda wondered this, but was never curious enough to ask.

Comment: Confirmed: Adding a tag to your list of favorite tags increases the follow count by one.  In near real-time, too; that's fairly impressive.

Comment: ok cool. Then what is **3.5k** number in this case then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the number of people who are following the **filter** on Stack Exchange. Filters are different in that they are *not* limited to a single tag. You can add multiple tags to them, and even span multiple sites. For example, I'm the only one following my specific "Favorite Tags" filter:

> [image: Favorite Tags Filter]

So, it would appear that there are 7 users on the Stack Exchange site itself who have followed the filter for that single tag on Stack Overflow, while there are 3,353 people following the tag on the actual Stack overflow site.

There is a difference with the subscription feature, though. Subscribing to a tag directly on a site automatically subscribes you to that tag's filter on Stack Exchange (they are one in the same). Following a tag on a specific site does not achieve the same result.

Comment: Great didn't knew correctly about filters.