# Who's also using my search filter?

Tags: support, tag-filters

I made a [search filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/78849/category-theory-interest) for myself and noticed that it has two users following.
I don't mind another user, but how do I find out who also has my same interest?

Comment: Why would you need to know that?

Comment: Now, you'll get more anonymous followers ;)

Comment: It would be nice to share info with them when learning?

Comment: I take it from the comments that it is anonymous by design. Fair enough.

Comment: @GuyCoder Since the filters does not provide this information, the question is a [meta-tag:feature-request]. Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: @tohecz All support questions are also (kind of) implied feature requests, e.g "I want to do foo, please tell me how (or if it's not possible, please build a feature to make it possible)". That said, let's keep the [feature-request] tag for concrete and explicit feature requests.

Comment: @Guy, I sure did, intriguing stuff in that search query!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156503/152859